# FFmpeg is encoding at a lower bitrate than what is specified

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, bitrate

I'm fairly new to FFmpeg, I'm using this command: ffmpeg -i "C:\FFmpeg\Handbrake\Trackmania\Trackmania.mp4" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -b:v 10000  -fps_mode passthrough "C:\FFmpeg\Handbrake\Trackmania\Compressed\AV1\QSV VERYSLOW.mp4", but FFmpeg is actually encoding at around 300kbps, which result in a horrible video quality. I've tried changing the bitrate, but this doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-b:v` is **bit**rate, so `10000` is `10 kbps`. You probably want `10000k`.

Comment: Thanks ! I was used to AV1 with QSV that had the bitrate in Kilobits by default